# When to use AsRef or other conversion traits for string-like type

Tags: rust

I'm defining a crate API in Rust stable (as of now, version 1.2) and am perplexed about best practices for defining my own string-like types.

For example, I have a `Foo` type that wraps a string.

```
pub struct Foo(String);
```

My API hides construction of `Foo` instances, and, furthermore, because the tuple field is private, the application cannot mistakenly construct an invalid `Foo` value for itself. This means my API restricts the application to work only with valid `Foo` values. So far so good.

However, I want the application to be able to use a `Foo` instance as though it's a string—say, printing it, logging it, writing it to a file, passing it to a third-party crate that accepts `&str`, constructing a copy via `to_string()` and mutating the copy, etc. In short, I want the application to be able to “cast away” `Foo`-ness and work with a reference to the underlying string. Because the application cannot convert the raw string back into a `Foo` instance, type-safety is preserved.

My question is: What conversion traits, if any, should my crate implement for `Foo` to allow the application to “cast away” `Foo`-ness and work with the underlying string as a raw string? It's important that `Foo` convert to `&str` so as to obviate any unnecessary copying of the underlying string.

For example, how about?

```
impl AsRef<str> for Foo
```

Is that the right thing to do? Is it enough to be idiomatic? Are there any other conversion traits I should consider implementing for `Foo`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a `Foo` *is* semantically a string, then implementing `Deref<Target = str>` (or possibly `Deref<Target = String>` and `DerefMut`) is the main thing to do. That will allow `&Foo` to coerce to `&str`, so you can write things like `&*foo` to get a `&str` out of a `Foo`, and `foo.starts_with("bar")` and such, calling methods that are defined on `str`.

Implementing `AsRef` is also going to be beneficial for some things. `Borrow` is another thing you *may* want to have, [though there are things to consider before doing so](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/book/first-edition/borrow-and-asref.html).

Comment: Your `starts_with` example clears up a lot. However, I've read the book section about `AsRef` and `Borrow`—still not clear. Does `AsRef` allow for coercion into a `&str` but without allowing for the `starts_with` example? What are some cases that I should implement `AsRef instead of `Deref`? Should I ever implement both?

Comment: `Deref` is magic and can be done for one type. `AsRef` is completely non-magic and can be done for multiple types. Implementing both is common.

Comment: I changed the link to the (deprecated) first-edition for two reasons: The [old desired link](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/borrow-and-asref.html) is more or less dead, and the page did not make it into second edition. However, you may add links to the documentation for [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) and [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html)